# Take screenshot of element (jpg,png) and then download it. Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a JS function which can take the screenshot from element and then download it.

```html
<body>
    <h1>Sample text</h1>
    <h2>Sample text</h2>
    <table width="1080px" height="1920px" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <img src="https://inspectiondoc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sample-icon.png" width="600px">
            </td>
            <td>
                Sample text
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background:#b6ff00">
            <td>
                Sample text
            </td>
            <td>
                Sample text
            </td>
            <td>
                Sample text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <h1>
        sample text
    </h1>
    <h2>Sample text</h2>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Capture" onclick="capture()">

</body>
```

After clicking capture button I want this td colspan="2" element to be screenshoted and downloaded on jpg or png format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take in-browser screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots)

Comment: Not quite but thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) could help you, it converts an element into a canvas, and then you just need to add its data as a url into an a element

```
function download(canvas, filename) {
  const data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
  const donwloadLink = document.querySelector("#download");
  donwloadLink.download = filename;
  donwloadLink.href = data;
}

html2canvas(document.querySelector(".card")).then((canvas) => {
  // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  download(canvas, "asd");
});
```

Check a full example here https://codepen.io/koseare/pen/NWpMjeP

Answer (score 0):

Try with `html2canvas`;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="all">
      <h2>Sample text</h2>
      <table width="1080px" height="1920px" style="border-collapse: collapse">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <img
                src="https://inspectiondoc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/sample-icon.png"
                width="600px"
              />
            </td>
            <td>Sample text</td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="background: #b6ff00">
            <td>Sample text</td>
            <td>Sample text</td>
            <td>Sample text</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Download" />
    <script>
      
      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener(
        "click",
        function () {
          var text = document.getElementById("all").value;
          var filename = "output.txt";
          download(filename, function makeScreenshot() {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("screenshot"), {scale: 1}).then(canvas => {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        });
    });
        },
        false
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```